# Radiobutton with RightToLeft and number leading Text moves number to end

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, radio-button

I've got radiobuttons with .RightToLeft set to Yes. The .Text values of these start with a digit, followed by a space and more text. For some reason, either VS or .net or whatever is moving that leading digit to the end of the string.

Anyone know why and/or how to fix?

[image: First RadioButton settings]
[image: RadioButton appearances]

(edit) Just tried to put quotes around the .Text string, just in case. Results were unexpected:
[image: With quotes]

Comment: You should not be using the `RightToLeft` property that way.  Read what it is actually for.  It's intended to support languages that read right to left, e.g. Arabic.

Comment: If what you actually want to achieve is to have English text on the left and the checkmark on the right then you should be changing the `CheckAlign` property to `MiddleRight` instead of `MiddleLeft`. This is why you read the documentation. You should read it first but you should at least read it before posting questions online if things don't work as expected. The Help menu in VS is not for decoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be misusing the `RightToLeft` property, which is to support right-to-left languages like Arabic. To place the check mark to the right of English text, set `CheckAlign` to `MiddleRight`.